# How to create a dynamic module in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

> I want to create a form like EmpCode, EmpName,EmpPhoto after submit
>   this that data save into database table and show on particular link
>   with employee's wise like EmpName: simmi, Empcode: 124 then photo.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

First Create a custom module.
Use hook_menu to create 2 menu items /my-form & /listing-page. Next Create a table to store your data in the database. For this you need to create .install file. Add all your fields and related configurations in this file. Refer this link - https://www.drupal.org/node/876250.
Finally Create a form by using hook_form, hook_form_validate and hook_form_submit. Refer - https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390